# ffmpeg error creating thumbnail different frame rate

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4

When using this at the command line I get very bad images with only grey or stripes in them.
It seems "the frame rate differs from container frame rate: 59.94 (60000/1001) -> 29.97 (30000/1001)".

Is there any way I can fix this in the ffmpeg statement?

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:10 -i FILENAME.mp4 -vframes 1 FILENAME.jpg
```

This is the output I get:

```
FFmpeg version 0.5.2, Copyright (c) 2000-2009 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --incdir=/usr/include --disable-avisynth --extra-cflags=-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-libdirac --enable-libfaac --enable-libfaad --enable-libfaadbin --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-swscale --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
  libavutil     49.15. 0 / 49.15. 0
  libavcodec    52.20. 1 / 52.20. 1
  libavformat   52.31. 0 / 52.31. 0
  libavdevice   52. 1. 0 / 52. 1. 0
  libavfilter    0. 4. 0 /  0. 4. 0
  libswscale     0. 7. 1 /  0. 7. 1
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
  built on Jun 13 2010 23:44:18, gcc: 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)
```

**Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 59.94 (60000/1001) -> 29.97 (30000/1001)**

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'FILENAME.mp4':
  Duration: 00:03:36.36, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1305 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: h264, yuv420p, 640x428, 29.97 tbr, 29.97 tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16
Output #0, image2, to 'FILENAME.jpg':
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 640x428, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 29.97 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
Press [q] to stop encoding
[h264 @ 0x307f6b0]brainfart cropping not supported, this could look slightly wrong ...
[h264 @ 0x307f6b0]AVC: Consumed only 14978 bytes instead of 14984
[h264 @ 0x307f6b0]AVC: Consumed only 1147 bytes instead of 1153
[h264 @ 0x307f6b0]Missing reference picture
[h264 @ 0x307f6b0]AVC: Consumed only 1947 bytes instead of 1953
[h264 @ 0x307f6b0]Missing reference picture
[h264 @ 0x307f6b0]AVC: Consumed only 1870 bytes instead of 1876
[h264 @ 0x307f6b0]Missing reference picture
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x307f6b0]AVC: Consumed only 810 bytes instead of 816
[h264 @ 0x307f6b0]Missing reference picture
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x307f6b0]AVC: Consumed only 955 bytes instead of 961
[h264 @ 0x307f6b0]Missing reference picture
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x307f6b0]AVC: Consumed only 1036 bytes instead of 1042
[h264 @ 0x307f6b0]Missing reference picture
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x307f6b0]AVC: Consumed only 998 bytes instead of 1004
[h264 @ 0x307f6b0]Missing reference picture
frame=    1 fps=  0 q=3.3 Lsize=      -0kB time=0.03 bitrate=  -5.3kbits/s
video:14kB audio:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead -100.149568%
```

Answer (score 0):

try this - seems like cropping is might be set wrong here. (height is not multiple of 16 thought that is invalid according to standard)

./ffmpeg -i ~/Sites/f3_voyage.mov  -ss 00:00:10 -f image2 -vframes 1 -s 640x432  FILENAME.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It seems like at 10 seconds you do not have a reference frame, Try this: `ffmpeg -i FILENAME.mp4 -ss 00:00:10 -vframes 1 FILENAME.jpg`. This will apply the -ss option on the output,ffpeg would have already decoded your file and hence this should work.